# Flex app and CSS with 960

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder

I am using the 960 grid system and I want my flex app to display inside this structure:

```
<div class="container_16">
  <div class="grid_14">
     Flex App here
 </div><!-- end flex div -->
```

I added this markup to the html wrapper created by Flex, but when I run the app nothing displays except for html that I have inserted before the flex app

Here is the main mark up:

```
 <body>
<div class="container_16">
    <div class="header grid_13">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <ul class="nav grid_10">
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- end header -->
    <div class="grid_12">
    <!-- SWFObject's dynamic embed method replaces this alternative HTML content with Flash content when enough 
         JavaScript and Flash plug-in support is available. The div is initially hidden so that it doesn't show
         when JavaScript is disabled.
    -->
    <div id="flashContent">
        <p>
            To view this page ensure that Adobe Flash Player version 
            ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is installed. 
        </p>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var pageHost = ((document.location.protocol == "https:") ? "https://" : "http://"); 
            document.write("<a href='http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer'><img src='" 
                            + pageHost + "www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif' alt='Get Adobe Flash player' /></a>" ); 
        </script> 
    </div>

    <noscript>
        <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="${width}" height="${height}" id="${application}">
            <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
            <param name="quality" value="high" />
            <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="${swf}.swf" width="${width}" height="${height}">
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
            <!--<![endif]-->
            <!--[if gte IE 6]>-->
                <p> 
                    Either scripts and active content are not permitted to run or Adobe Flash Player version
                    ${version_major}.${version_minor}.${version_revision} or greater is not installed.
                </p>
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash Player" />
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </noscript>
```

Comment: What is the markup afterwards, ie what does `${swf}.swf` turn into?